# How to fix the @import or @use error in angular v17 when using the tilde ~ from third party aoftware

Tags: angular, sass

In my angular v17 project I'm using a third party software package. To get its styles I need to add some `@use` statements in my `styles.scss`

```
@use '@thirdparty/magic/src/styles/magic-font
```

Inside that font scss file they do something like the following:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'A magic font'
     ...
     src: 
       url('~@thirdparty/magic/dist/assets/fonts/a-magic-font.woff') format('woff2');
}
```

That `~` seems to break my build!

Now, when I build my project I get

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve ~@thirdparty/magic/dist/assets/fonts/a-magic-font.woff
```

Below that error a solution is provided:

```
  You can remove the tilde and use a relative path to reference it, which should remove this error.
  Preprocessor stylesheets may not show the exact file location of the error.
```

But, as I said, the files are not mine, they are downloaded (node_modules/npm) so I cannot remove the `~`

What would be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tilde imports are not standard. Their usage have been deprecated since [v15](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/23787).

You'll need to ask the third party to remove it.

Or you could rely on [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to do this change on your side.